# How to create a pair of dates (date_combo) using the Form API?

Tags: 7, datetime

The **Date** module provide a field type called `date_combo` that allows a date feld to collect both a start date and an end date.

It works as expected when I use the GUI to create a content type with a date field an tick the box for the field setting saying: "Collect an end date" (i.e. you get an extra date field for the end date on the form to create new content).

I want to use the the `date_combo` content type when I construct a form using the Drupal API.  So far, I've inspected the form that is created by the GUI, and tried to duplicate this.  But I am getting errors complaining about undefined indices in the form.  For example:

```
Notice: Undefined index: #field_name in date_combo_element_process() (line 259 of .../sites/all/modules/date/date_elements.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #bundle in date_combo_element_process() (line 261 of .../sites/all/modules/date/date_elements.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #entity_type in date_combo_element_process() (line 262 of .../sites/all/modules/date/date_elements.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #language in date_combo_element_process() (line 263 of .../sites/all/modules/date/date_elements.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #field_parents in field_widget_field() (line 577 of .../modules/field/field.form.inc).
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
  $form['datepair']['arrdep'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        0 => 'field-type-datestamp',
        1 => 'field-name-rbg-unixtime',
        2 => 'field-widget-date-text',
      ),
    ),
    '#weight' => 1,
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
      0 => array(
        '#entity_type' => 'node',
        '#bundle' => 'rbg_booking',
        '#field_name' => 'field_rbg_unixtime',
        '#language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
        '#field_parents' => array(),
      ),
      '#entity_type' => 'node',
      '#bundle' => 'rbg_booking',
      '#field_name' => 'field_rbg_unixtime',
      '#language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
      '#field_parents' => array(),
    ),
    '#entity_type' => 'node',
    '#bundle' => 'rbg_booking',
    '#field_name' => 'field_rbg_unixtime',
    '#field_parents' => array(),
    '#access' => TRUE,
    'arrdep' => array(
      '#title' => t('A pair of dates:'),
      '#description' => t('Description'),
      '#type' => 'date_combo',
      '#theme_wrappers' => array(
        0 => 'date_combo',
      ),
      '#size' => 8,
      '#default_value' => array(
        'value' => $date,
        'value2' => $date2,
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
        'data_type' => 'datestamp',
      ),
      '#date_timezone' => 'UTC',
      '#element_validate' => array (
        0 => 'date_combo_validate',
      ),
      '#date_is_default' => TRUE,
      '#date_items' => array(
        'value' => $date,
        'value2' => $date2,
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
        'data_type' => 'datestamp',
      ),

    ),
  );
```

Guidance regarding how to make use of he `date_combo` construct by means of the Form API will be much appreciated.